# ServiceStack.Redis: Unable to Connect: sPort: 50071

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis, redisclient

I'm using the ServiceStack Redis Client and I was hoping that I could get a clarification on what might cause the following error ... "Unable to Connect: sPort: 50071"?  I'm using the "PooledRedisClientManager" object for connections.  Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

IF YOU ARE USING A **SELF HOSTED** REDIS SERVER AND USING THE [Service Stack Redis Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) **THEN BUYER BEWARE**

As of 9/23/2015

Service Stack does license validation in the client code (rather than the server). If you are ripping through a lot of messages 6000+ an hour you will get.  The resulting error is

```
Unable to Connect: sPort:
```

However, it is not handling their custom LicenseExpection and exposing the error correctly.  The error would be something like this:

```
The free-quota limit on '6000 Redis requests per hour' has been reached. Please see https://servicestack.net to upgrade to a commercial license or visit https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3 to revert back to the free ServiceStack v3.
```

I doubt you have imposed such a limit on your server :-)

Comment: Ouch. Lost a lot of time on this one. The worst part is that we are paying customers, but forgot to add the license key to one of our batch programs we had deployed on a remote server. So we spent a lot of time looking at ports and other nonsense. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a time out issue, try increasing it:

```
pooledRedisClientManager.ConnectTimeout = 1000
```

You need to check that you are not creating a new PooledRedisClientManager for each request / usage. You will quickly run out of ports. Use a singleton approach in a web environment.